# Include a C file in the makefile of a C++ application?

Tags: c++, makefile

I'm trying to include a C library then compile it along with my C++ application but I can't get my makefile work properly:

```
SRC = main.cpp menu.cpp dialog_wnd.cpp player.cpp
C_SRC = miniaudio.c
CXX = g++ 
CXXFLAGS = -Wall $(shell fltk-config --cxxflags)

LFLAGS = $(shell fltk-config --ldflags)

OBJS = $(SRC:.cpp=.o) $(C_SRC:.c=.o)
DIR_OBJ = obj/
DIR_OBJS = $(addprefix $(DIR_OBJ), $(OBJS))

$(DIR_OBJ)%.o: %.cpp %.c *.h 
        $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $(<) -o $(@)

EXE = myApplication

all: $(EXE)

$(EXE): $(DIR_OBJS)
        $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LFLAGS)

depend:
        makedepend -- $(CXXFLAGS) -- $(SRC) $(C_SRC)

strip: $(EXE)
        strip --strip-all $(EXE)

clean:
        rm -f $(DIR_OBJS)
        rm -f $(EXE)
```

I get this error:

> make: *** No rule to make target 'obj/main.o', needed by
> 'myApplication'.

What did I do wrong ?

Comment: I'm no expert at Make, but I think your pattern rule says "obj/foo.o is made from foo.c and foo.cpp and any .h files together". But you have either .c or .cpp, not both for any given single object.

Comment: Make your life easier and do `OBJS = $(SRC:.cpp=.cpp.o) $(C_SRC:.c=.c.o)`. This allows you to write separate rules for compiling C and C++: `$(DIR_OBJECT)%.c.o: %.c ...` `$(DIR_OBJECT)%.cpp.o: %.cpp ...`. You should probably be introducing `CC = gcc` for compiling C code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(DIR_OBJ)%.o: %.cpp %.c *.h` makes every object file require **both** a corresponding `.cpp` **and** `.c` file.

I suggest splitting it in two, which also makes it possible to use the proper compiler (`$(CC)`) for the C code. For the flags, use `CPPFLAGS` for options that you want both to use and `CFLAGS` for flags to be used by the C compiler.

Example:

```
CPPFLAGS = -Wall
CXXFLAGS = $(shell fltk-config --cxxflags)

$(DIR_OBJ)%.o: %.cpp *.h 
        $(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS)-c $< -o $@

$(DIR_OBJ)%.o: %.c *.h 
        $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

Note: Making each object file depend on every header file will require a full rebuild every time you touch a single header file.